# 404 Error with RESTful webservice using Jersey

Tags: jersey, http-status-code-404

I have been spending hours trying to figure out why I am gettin 404 error. I have checked similar postings in Stackoverflow, but I am still having a problem.

I know it runs on Tomcat and can display index file. But, when I try to test RESTful ws with the following url, http://localhost:8080/RestWs/rest/hello, 
I get 404 error:

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestWs</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

My resource class in Java:
package DemoRest;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

I downloaded Jersey jars from https://jersey.github.io/download.html# 
and copied the jars in the WEB/INF/lib folder.
The extracted jaxrs-ri-2.26 jar has three folders - api, ext and lib. I copied all jars from these folders to the WEB/INF/lib folder.

I am wondering if I am missing some jars or they are not in a right location. However, I checked most of the related postings in the stackoverflow for solution, but I was not successful.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: when you start your server, do you see in the console that ur ws is exposed at  http://localhost:8080/RestWs/rest/?

Comment: This is part of the console:                                                            
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 01, 2018 7:46:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 01, 2018 7:46:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13397 ms

Comment: In the console, I see this error: "INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.82\wtpwebapps\RestWs\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class". The solutions people used was to mark as "provided" in maven pom file. However, I am not using maven.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  One solution I found worked. I had to download JaxWs jar from https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws and copy jaxws-rt.jar into Tomcat lib folder.